# Why isn't dvips finding my Type 1 fonts?

Tags: fonts, dvips

I've installed Cygwin on two Windows 7 machines.  Both of them have the Adobe basic 35 fonts installed in the system as Type 1 fonts.  Yet when I run a file that uses, say, Palatino through dvips, the resulting PostScript output uses Palatino-Roman on one machine and URWPalladioL-Roma on the other.

I created the dvi file by giving the following input to LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{palatino}
\title{Testing}
\begin{document}
This text should come out in Palatino.
\end{document}
```

It doesn't get much simpler than that.

What's a good strategy for figuring out why dvips finds the Adobe fonts on one machine and not on the other?

Comment: Some more information: It looks like what is going on is that in the process of installing Cygwin, I also wound up installing the "URW Base 35" fonts, which are intended as replacements for the 35 fonts in Adobe Type Basics. Somewhere, dvips is deciding to substitute these fonts for the adobe fonts.

Is there a way to tell dvips not to do so?

Comment: Compile your document with pdflatex and show the log-file. Also convert your postscript with ps2pdf to a pdf and then check e.g. in the adobe reader if all fonts are embedded.

Answer (score 2):

I found it!  The answer is to execute this command once:

```
updmap --setoption LW35=ADOBE --setoption dvipsDownloadBase35=false
```

The first of these options tells dvips to use the Adobe fonts instead of the free replacements; the second tells it not to attempt to embed those fonts (which are not part of the standard TeX distribution) in the output PostScript.

When the PostScript is converted to PDF, Acrobat will do the right thing with the Adobe fonts.

Comment: JFTR, for recent TeX Live, you need to use `updmap-user` (or `-sys`, depending on your preference). Also, you only use `ADOBE` if your fonts don't have the Karl Berry naming (which they will most likely have, if you install a modern distribution). If you don't have the Adobe fonts with their original filenames, then you have to use `LW35=ADOBEkb` instead.