# How to run this template of latex in a Mac OS TexLive?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, texlive, mactex

[CASthesis-v0.2.zip](http://www.ctex.org/PackageCASthesis/files.xml?action=download&file=CASthesis-v0.2.zip)

Above is a template for writing thesis in Chinese. (Fortunately, there is not very much Chinese content in this template.) It works well on a Windows machine. But when I run it on a Mac OS machine, there are errors. The error information is shown as below.
[image]

It says that 'Error: Wrong DVI mode driver option 'dvipdfm', because XeTex is running.' But I was told that this template can support XeTex. Please check it for me if there is anything I should modify or setup.

---

Update: Above problem is solved by changing the coding environment. But a new problem appear. The error information is as below.

> Output written on template.dvi (35 pages, 103108 bytes). SyncTeX
>   written on template.synctex.gz. Transcript written on template.log.
>
> #### /usr/texbin/dvips -R -Poutline  -o /tmp/altpdflatex.5730-1359428424/template.ps template.dvi This is
>
> dvips(k) 5.991 Copyright 2011 Radical Eye Software
>   (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2013.01.29:1400' ->
>   /tmp/altpdflatex.5730-1359428424/template.ps
>
> kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode ljfour --bdpi 600 --mag 1+123/600
>   --dpi 723 gbksong41 mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for gbksong41. mktexpk: perhaps gbksong41 is missing from the map file.
>   kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
>   /usr/texbin/dvips: Font gbksong41 not found; using cmr10
>
> /usr/texbin/dvips: ! invalid char 169 from font gbksong41
>
> #### FAILED to generate /tmp/altpdflatex.5730-1359428424/template.ps ()

Comment: You need to remove the `dvipdfm` option from the `\documentclass` command in the template file. Also make sure that you have reencoded the file as UTF-8.  (I did this with `iconv` in the Terminal): `iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 template.tex > newtemplate.tex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn, Thx. The above mentioned problem was solved when I change the coding environment from "Mac OS Roman" to "GB 18030". And the compiling process can run well. But another problem appeared. After compiling, it fails to generate a ps output. The error information is as I modified in the question.

Comment: @datcn: That's a different problem: `dvips` can not find the font. See [Why isn't dvips finding my Type 1 fonts?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48090)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original problem here is that the encoding of the file is incorrect. Make sure that the encoding is UTF-8. (I'm not sure that the GB 18030 encoding is guaranteed to work with XeTeX.)  You can change the encoding using `iconv`:

```
iconv -f GB2312 -t UTF-8 template.tex > newtemplate.tex
```

You also need to  remove the `divpdfm` option from the `\documentclass` command, in the `template.tex` file.

The second problem based on your edit is different: in this case you need to make sure that you run the file with XeLaTeX and not LaTeX+dvips.